# Parentheses and order of operations

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I have a function in java that returns an integer. I know what it is supposed to return so I know when it runs correctly or not. Anyway, there is this line of code at some point in a for loop:

If I write it like this

```
miuf = miuf_ant * nf_ant / nf - ((double) ((t - 1) * hist[t - 1]) / (double) nf);`
```

the result is fine.

If I write it like this

```
miuf = (miuf_ant * (nf_ant / nf) - ((double) ((t - 1) * hist[t - 1]) / (double) nf));
```

the result is way off.

`nf_ant`, `nf` and `t` are `int`s, the rest are `double`s.

I have evaluated these 2 expressions in the debugger for a few iterations and the results differ by some 0.3 in general. Why does this happen and why is it that one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: Isn't this obvious?  You've set your own rules for order of operations.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq Mathematically, these 2 writings are equivalent. So don't come with such comments. It's the programming part(how the results are evaluated) that I was confused about so I asked. Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nf_ant` and `nf` are `int`s, your problem is that the second version if performing *integer division* and not *floating point division*. You need to cast one of them first.

Let's compare the following two expressions:

```
miuf_ant * nf_ant / nf
miuf_ant * (nf_ant / nf)
```

The first one is equivalent to the following by the rules of Java:

```
(miuf_ant * nf_ant) / nf
```

What happens here is that the product is evaluated first, and because `miuf_ant` is `double`, the result is also a `double`. Afterwards, the same happends for the division.

In the "bad" (second) case though, because both division operators are `int`s, the result is also an `int`, losing precission on the operation by effectively truncating the result. This loss of precission is then carried to the product.

Comment: Please mention the loss of precision in the second case instead of saying "an operand that is mathematically not what you intended" and I will give you the answer. It is well explained otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, `nf_ant / nf` will be computed in integer arithmetic as the parentheses mean it's evaluated on its own. This loss of the remainder is the cause of the difference.

In the first case it is premultiplied by `miuf_ant` which is a floating point type. Since `*` and `/` have the same precedence, all 3 arguments are promoted to floating point prior to computation.

Comment: Ok, I see. So in the second case, because nf_ant and nf are both ints and they sit inside parentheses, they are evaluated to an int and I lose some precision. In the first case the double is multiplied by the int and the result goes into a double. Then it is divided by the other int ant the result goes, again, into a double. So this way I don't lose precision. Thank you.

Comment: That's almost it aside from the fact that formally the `int`s are actually promoted to the floating point before evaluation. Note this is true in C and C++ too. I can't speak for other languages.

Comment: They are promoted, but with 0 after the decimal mark, so I lose all the digits that were supposed to be there.

Comment: Yup, in the second case, the result of `nf_ant / nf` (which is an integral type) will be promoted to floating point. But by then the precision will be lost.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me giving the answer to Darkhogg, because I think he explained it in more detail for a total beginner to understand. I am actually quite far from being a total beginner in java, even if my question may suggest otherwise, and I understood what you meant immediately because I must have read about it quite a few times and the answer just came back to me on the spot. Hope you don't mind and thanks!

Comment: Not at all. I like that answer too. Just upvoted it.